# When Java's Garbage collector reclaims memory?

Tags: java, arrays

I know that Arrays of primitive type are implicitly initialized to 0 in java.
So if I have a code :

```
public class Foo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] arr = new int[50];
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
            arr[i] = i;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){      // This Line
             System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know if memory from arr[30] to arr[49] would already have been reclaimed by garbage collector at the line which has the comment?

Comment: As the answers state: it's still referenced, so: no. but even if it weren't, you, as a developer, can not influence when the garbage collector runs. Basically, it runs when your environment detects the need to run the GC.

Comment: Your program is too small and ends too fast. The garbage collector will likely never run within the execution time of this program.

Answer (score 12):

> I want to know if memory from arr[30] to arr[49] would already have been reclaimed by garbage collector at the line which has the comment?

No, absolutely not. The array is a single object. It's either reachable, or it's not reachable... and in this case, it's still reachable.

In a more complex example, if this were a `String[]`, I wouldn't expect the strings referenced by elements `arr[30]` to `arr[49]` to be eligible for garbage collection, either. A very smart GC *might* be able to tell which parts of an array are unused and not include those in GC roots, but I don't think I've ever seen that. (It would have to know that no other code ever had a reference to the array, for one thing. It seems an unusual situation, and therefore one probably not worth optimizing.)

Answer (score 2):

No they would not have been reclaimed - because there is still an active reference to them.

As soon as the garbage collector notices that some objects are not in use anymore, it will mark them for deletion. (A referenced object is an which still has a pointer to it).

After they are marked for deletion - a later cycle of the garbage collection will delete the actual object. This will cause some more free space to appear in those places.

After the objects are deleted - the remaining used space is compacted (so all the empty space sits together, essentially).